# How actor should handle responses from other actors?

Tags: scala, akka

My question is about handling response in actor from other actors and perform some action with these results.

Here it is short pseudo example of recieve method:

```
case data: Data =>
    val data2 = actor1 ? data.fieldA
    val almostFinished = data2.flatMap { d2 => 
        val data3 = actor2 ? d2.fieldB
        data3.map { d3 => 
            actor3 ? someStuff(d3)
        }
    }
    almostFinished.map { r =>
        someFinalStuff(r)
    } pipeTo sender
```

Here it is some general business processing logic here.

First of all it looks complete unreadable.
Second - the failures in maps are not handled and not reported nowhere.

Could you please explain how should I handle such kind of logic in terms of actors and messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for the code being unreadable, some `for` syntax could give us some refreshment

```
case data: Data =>
  val combinedFuture: Future[Stuff] =
    for {
      data2 <- actor1 ? data.fieldA
      data3 <- actor2 ? data2.fieldB
      stuff <- actor3 ? someStuff(data3)
    } yield someFinalStuff(stuff)

  combinedFuture pipeTo sender
```

In fact your example seems to be made up exactly to showcase the usefulness of `for-comprehension`

---

As for the issue of detecting failures within your "future calls pipeline", you may want to know that a `Future[A]` type can have only one of two possible instances:

```
Success[A]
Failure[T <: Throwable]
```

you can test the type or better still, you should use the `onComplete`, `onSuccess`, `onFailure` callback methods, defined on the [Future](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future) class

As dr.Kuhn clarified, piping a failed Future using `pipeTo` will deliver a `Status.Failure` message to the recipient, from which you can obtain the error as a `Throwable` instance

**edit**

As cmbaxter noticed, the `?` pattern will return an "untyped" Future, that will need some sort of coercion to give back the correctly typed value, using `mapTo`

The correct code will become

```
  val combinedFuture: Future[Stuff] =
    for {
      data2 <- (actor1 ? data.fieldA).mapTo[Data2]
      data3 <- (actor2 ? data2.fieldB).mapTo[Data3]
      stuff <- (actor3 ? someStuff(data3)).mapTo[Intermediate]
    } yield someFinalStuff(stuff)
```

Comment: pipeTo will send a Status.Failure message to the given ActorRef in case some operation on the Futures failed.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach than using ask and futures is to use a temporary actor together with the [Aggregator Pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/contrib/aggregator.html) that was introduced in Akka 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a try:

```
case data: Data =>
  val data2Fut = (actor1 ? data.fieldA).mapTo[Data]
  val result = 
    for{
      data2 <- data2Fut
      data3 <- (actor2 ? data2.fieldB).mapTo[Data]
      data4 <- (actor3 ? someStuff(data3)).mapTo[Data]
    } yield someFinalStuff(data4)
  result pipeTo sender
```

Any time you find yourself chaining together `flatMap` and `map` you should consider cleaning up by using a for-comprehension like this.